# Parse SVG XML to get background color

Tags: javascript, svg, xml-parsing, fabricjs

I need to extract the background color of an SVG's XML so I can use it as a variable elsewhere. I get my SVG XML from an HTML5 canvas (FabricJS) using a toSVG method and can clearly see, via a console log, the SVG XML containing the background color, but am unsure of how to parse this out.

Comment: can you paste a small svg to see where the background color is?

Comment: Here you go, although I am now wondering if it may be easier to just get the canvas background from FabricJS: <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="25.999960in" height="12.937441in" style="background-color: #72a149" viewBox="0 0 650 323.44" xml:space="preserve">

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing. I am able to get the canvas background color as follows:

```
var bkColor = canvas.backgroundColor;
```